# Object.create and init

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an intro to Javascript course and need some help with best practices and some overall feedback as my teacher seems waaay too uninterested in helping us students since he has tenure.

**Full disclaimer: The code beneath compiles and is *correct* (judging from the test-cases that the professor has provided). So I don't need help with the actual assignment, but how to interpret the use case of an init bundled with create() and any (if any...) logic behind the exercise.**

```
/**
 * Exercise 2.2
 *
 * Create a method 'shape.init(x, y, height, width)' that helps you to
 * initiate a object. Try it out by re-initing 'shape1' using the method.
 *
 * Answer with 'shape1.print()'.
 *
 * Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.
 */

function shape(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.width = 0;
}

shape.print = function(){
  return 'x:' + this.x + ', ' +
         'y:' + this.y + ', ' +
         'height:' + this.height + ', ' +
         'width:' + this.width;
}

var shape1 = Object.create(shape, {x : {value : 29},
                                  y : {value : 56},
                                  height : {value : 17},
                                  width : {value : 19}});


shape.init = function(x, y, height, widht){
    function shape(x, y, height, width){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    }
}

shape1.init(29, 56, 17, 19);


ANSWER = shape1.print();
```

What I have a difficult time following is why you would need an init-function in when you can use object.create() (which in my mind works the same as an init)...

Is the teacher just being ignorant at this point, or are there cases where implementing an init where you are already are using a object.create() to initialize object truly is worth it?

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific. I'm not sure which bits need clarification. Part of that might be because this is not much like JS idioms.

Comment: Well, what I'm unsure about is why we would need an init in any case we are using object.create(), basically. For me they are the one and same; one initializes old-school objects ('classes' in java) the other initalizes objects by a reference to an already defined object and it's properties...

Comment: The `init` function seems incorrect. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @geostocker the constructor, `init` method, and `Object.create` call are *all* duplicates of one another in this case. Especially since they're all trying to set the parameters, although the `Object.create` call uses **completely** different params.

Comment: Your code may work as intended, but both `shap1.init` and `function shape` are doing nothing.

Comment: What is purpose of creating `shape1`? Could you use existing `shape` function  with parameters and `||` included when setting properties?

Comment: I infer that your teacher wrote the `Object.create` and `shape` code, which makes their javascript expertise questionable. I posted an answer that is probably what they are expecting you to write. However I must add that none of the code in my answer (nor the code you provided) is conventional javascript. It's more of a hacky/misguided approach to OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer mostly tries to follow the spirit of the exercise, rather than what is "correct" or standard javascript convention.)

The answer is most likely to wrap it into a function:

```
shape.init = function(x, y, height, width) {
     return Object.create(shape, {x : {value : x},
                                  y : {value : y},
                                  height : {value : height},
                                  width : {value : width}});
};

shape1 = shape.init(29, 56, 17, 19); // now creating a shape is simply 1 function call

ANSWER = shape1.print();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Would you mind adding an explenation as to why it's not considered good practice? :)

Comment: @geostocker There are other sources that would explain it better than me. The standard approach to OOP would be creating a class-like function. Something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Custom_objects.

Comment: Gotcha, basic constructor stuff, then. I'll not put too much effort into understanding the prof's thought-process in regards to this assignment, then. 
I'm sure you can see my confusion. I've nearly got a degree in SE and thought I'd take this course for extra credit. Didn't realize it was gonna be so confusing... :p

Answer (score 0):

1.Dont use Object.create. 
*new* looks much better:

```
shape1= new shape(args);
//this just works together with the thing guest answered
```

1b. Yep youre right, init doesnt make sense, it would if you generate custom objects:

```
shape={};
shape.init=function(args){
return {};
}
shape1=shape.init(args);
```

2. Use prototyping, as its better for the memory consumption:

   shape.prototype.print=function(){
   }

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` `||` where properties are set. Not certain what purpose of `shape1`, `shape.init` or `Object.create()` is?

```
function Shape(x, y, height, width){
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.height = height || 0;
    this.width = width || 0;
}

var shape1 = new Shape(29, 56, 17, 19);
var shape2 = new Shape(1, 2, 3, 4);
var shape3 = new Shape();
```